# Body background image ignoring margin

Tags: css, background, margin

A quick problem;

I have a number of complete and very complex websites that i am activating a cookie acceptance script on. The cookie message wrapper appears at the top of the body wrapper.

On a number of these websites (mainly the e-commerce sites) there are quite a few pages that utilise the body tag for branding background images. This is unavoidable due to the back end system used.

The method i'm using is to set the body top margin to to say 200px, then a negative 200px top margin on the cookie wrapper.

The problem is that the body background does not respect that margin. If the background position is set to top, it sits to the top of the window and ignores the body margin. I could set the background top position to 200px but that would screw up pages where the background top position was already set to a different value...

I'm simply looking for a way to make that background respect the body margin without affecting any other parts of the layout.

Comment: afaik you'll have to change the background position of your image as it will not move with margin-top applied to the body tag.

Comment: No sorry, i can't list client websites, im just looking for an example on the web.

Comment: You can't reposition the background on a body element that way, nor can you achieve it with padding on the html element. Maybe you can get the background-top attribute with whichever javascript library you're using, and add 200 to it until the user dismisses your cookie box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to handle this problem. On document ready, check if there is a cookie wrapper div. If it exists, change background position.